# Disable change password email on user import

Tags: php, silverstripe

When CSV importing users into Silverstripe 3.6 the password changed email gets sent out.
Is there a way to prevent this email getting sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this behaviour comes from the fact that the Password field on Member is "changed" during the import process (from nothing to something). If you look at `Member::onBeforeWrite` it checks for a config property "notify_password_change", which you could temporarily override with a custom loader:

```
class NoEmailMemberCsvBulkLoader extends MemberCsvBulkLoader
{
    public function load($filepath)
    {
        try {
            Config::nest()
            Config::inst()->update('Member', 'notify_password_change', false);
            return parent::load($filepath);
        } finally {
            Config::unnest();
        }
    }
}
```

You could then tell SilverStripe to use your importer instead. The problem here is that `MemberImportForm::doImport` instantiates `MemberCsvBulkLoader` directly, so you cannot overload it with the injector, or set it any other way. This is a shame.

A short term option, since importing CSVs for *you* (note: not a client you may have) would be to disable this config setting in one of your `_config.php` files while you're doing the imports.

You might consider a pull request to the framework to make the areas where `new MemberCsvBulkLoader` is used injectable. Another option is to make a pull request directly to `MemberCsvBulkLoader` to set this config option on Member, since you're probably not the first person who thinks this is odd behaviour for a bulk import tool.

Hope this helps!